# I want to set older domain name with same account and another account in Branch.io

Tags: ionic-framework, dns, branch.io

Domain is incorrectly set up; please use the nameservers below as your NS record. A CNAME record is not required. If you've already done this, note that it can take up to several hours to propagate.
ns-97.awsdns-12.com.
ns-814.awsdns-37.net.
ns-1931.awsdns-49.co.uk.
ns-1065.awsdns-05.org.

Comment: Please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And even besides the form of the question, since its subject is not about programming, it is completely off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use same domain name for two different Branch accounts. If would like to use your old domain for your new account please write into